# Chrome developer tools "search all sources" stuck

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome developer tools search all sources is not working when a js execution is paused at a breakpoint. It is really annoying that I cannot search for some function across all sources when we are debugging.

How do I resolve this? I am on chrome version 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit)

[image: Screenshot of the search window]

Comment: Seeing this as well...

Comment: This happens when the download of certain script files are pending due to the pause at the breakpoint. I started using a new tab without the breakpoints to search for code.